# Can google accounts be restored to a phone that was factory reset or wasn't backed up properly?

Tags: root-access, accounts

My phone was rooted, and I forgot to make a backup of everything, I backed up contacts, messages, photos, videos, music, and all my files obviously but there are things you can not back up before you root like your App data, phone messages, google accounts.

And I had a school account from high school that I lost, I don't care about the apps but when it was deleted, my phone removed all those accounts after it was finished rooting and I had a bunch of Google accounts.

Is there a way I can restore the google accounts because I don't know or remember the passwords as they were stored on the device? What I mean is that if you had synced a bunch of Google accounts to your Samsung phone, wouldn't you be able to get them back if the accounts were made using that device.

I was able to log in to the account when I reset one of my Google passwords by entering my password to unlock the phone. If not, is there a way to see the email of all the Google accounts I made using the specific phone?

Comment: Google accounts usually do not store any passwords on the device. Google services use oAuth authentication system that requires username/password only on first login. Afterwards you are getting a "data token" (oAuth refresh token) that is used instead of username/password.

Comment: @Robert can these data tokens be redistributed to a phone if it was saved on the device before reset because I know google keeps a history of all devices on every account

Comment: Restoring those tokens may work, however there is a problem: Those tokens are refreshed regularly (I don't know the time scale - may be every month or half year?). If a token is refreshed you are getting a new token which replaces the old one. Therefore if the token has been used after the backup has been made then token in the backup is already used up.